# Await for Task in C# not returing

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I am having an issue with the below code. In Debug it runs to the }); part after return true but never returns to the calling method. The below methods should connect to a zebra printer, send the ZLP code print and check the status after to ensure printing was successful. Then return true or false (will add exception handling after) and if true commit to the database the values printed.

```
private Boolean printLabel(string productName, double productWeight, String customerLabelType, String scaleNumber, String packageDate, String lotNumber, String barCode)
{
    string s = dao.getCustomerLabel(customerLabelType);
    s = s.Replace("<<<product_weight>>>", productWeight.ToString());
    s = s.Replace("<<<product type>>>>", productName);
    s = s.Replace("<<<barcode>>>", barCode);
    s = s.Replace("<<<Packed Date:>>>", packageDate);
    s = s.Replace("<<<Lot Number:>>>", lotNumber);
    //  RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter("ZDesigner GX420d", s);
    string ipAddress = dao.getPrinterIp(scaleNumber);

    try
    {
        return PrintOneLabelTask(ipAddress, s).Result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return false;
}

private async Task<Boolean> PrintOneLabelTask(string theIpAddress, String ZPL_STRING)
{             
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Instantiate connection for ZPL TCP port at given address
        Connection thePrinterConn = new TcpConnection(theIpAddress, TcpConnection.DEFAULT_ZPL_TCP_PORT);

        ZebraPrinter printer = PrintHelper.Connect(thePrinterConn, PrinterLanguage.ZPL);
        PrintHelper.SetPageLanguage(printer);
        if (PrintHelper.CheckStatus(printer))
        {
            PrintHelper.Print(printer, ZPL_STRING);
            if (PrintHelper.CheckStatusAfter(printer))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Label Printed");
            }
        }
        printer = PrintHelper.Disconnect(printer);
        Console.WriteLine("Done Printing");
        return true;
    });

    return false;
}
```

Comment: What's the exact purpose of using `await Task.Run(()` in `PrintOneLabelTask`? You're using async-over-sync just to freeze the thread with `.Result;`. You could either remove that Task.Run (useless to schedule I/O work that way) or go async all the way (and make `printLabel` async too, and its callers). Also, the situation you describe is known as *deadlock*

Comment: Possible deadlock at `.Result`.

Comment: Yea thanks after reworking the code i added <code>return Task.Run(async () => await PrintOneLabelTask(ipAddress, s)).Result;</code> and modified the PrintOneLabelTask to be async and removed the await

Answer (score 2):

When you `return` from a lambda expression, you are exiting the lambda expression and returning control to `PrintOneLabelTask`. You are not returning *from* `PrintOneLabelTask` at all. So in your code, the `PrintOneLabelTask` method will *always* return false.

You need to capture the result and return that instead.

```
private async Task<Boolean> PrintOneLabelTask(string theIpAddress, String ZPL_STRING)
{
    bool result = false;
     
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Instantiate connection for ZPL TCP port at given address
        Connection thePrinterConn = new TcpConnection(theIpAddress, TcpConnection.DEFAULT_ZPL_TCP_PORT);

        ZebraPrinter printer = PrintHelper.Connect(thePrinterConn, PrinterLanguage.ZPL);
        PrintHelper.SetPageLanguage(printer);
        if (PrintHelper.CheckStatus(printer))
        {
            PrintHelper.Print(printer, ZPL_STRING);
            if (PrintHelper.CheckStatusAfter(printer))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Label Printed");
            }
        }
        printer = PrintHelper.Disconnect(printer);
        Console.WriteLine("Done Printing");
        result = true;
    });

    return result;
}
```

Note: There are probably some other problems in your code... e.g., I don't see any possible scenario where the method will return false.

Comment: While this is true, the question seems to be around the deadlock caused by the `.Result` call in the calling method: "... but never returns to the calling method"

Comment: Or even simpler `return await Task.Run(() =>...`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be experiencing a deadlock caused by the [SynchronizationContext](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/) of your framework.

When you access `Result` of the `Task<bool>` returned from `PrintOneLabelTask`, you are blocking the current thread until that task is completed.

The `Task<bool>` is returned as soon as you hit `await Task.Run(() =>`: `Task.Run` returns another `Task` that will complete once the provided delegate has run to completion on the ThreadPool.

However, if your `SynchronizationContext` schedules continuations back onto the calling thread, it will attempt to resume `PrintOneLabelTask` on a thread that is already being blocked by `Result`.

There is your deadlock.

---

**The solution**

`PrintOneLabelTask` isn't really asynchronous at all; it is a synchronous method that is being run on the ThreadPool.

This isn't a problem as such, but it can lead to unmaintainable code with issues like the one you are currently experiencing.

The method should be written as the synchronous operation it is:

```
private void PrintOneLabel(string theIpAddress, string ZPL_STRING)
{             
    // Instantiate connection for ZPL TCP port at given address
    Connection thePrinterConn = new TcpConnection(theIpAddress, TcpConnection.DEFAULT_ZPL_TCP_PORT);

    ZebraPrinter printer = PrintHelper.Connect(thePrinterConn, PrinterLanguage.ZPL);
    PrintHelper.SetPageLanguage(printer);
    if (PrintHelper.CheckStatus(printer))
    {
        PrintHelper.Print(printer, ZPL_STRING);
        if (PrintHelper.CheckStatusAfter(printer))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Label Printed");
        }
    }
    printer = PrintHelper.Disconnect(printer);
    Console.WriteLine("Done Printing");
}
```

(The method should also be `void` rather than `bool` because there is no situation where `false` could be returned).

Then call the method synchronously:

```
try
{
    PrintOneLabel(ipAddress, s);
    return true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}

return false;
```

If you are building an app that has a UI thread, and this now causes your UI to freeze, then decide to offload to the ThreadPool *at the highest level possible* (usually an event handler):

```
public async void YourEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
    bool result = await Task.Run(() => printLabel(//...
    //...
}
```